# Xcode 3 gcc 4.2 error: 'min' was not declared in this scope

Tags: xcode, gcc

for some reason now and again xcode/gcc4.2 complains about

```
error: 'min' was not declared in this scope
```

and the same for max

it seems to happen totally randomly, even if i #define them my self at a top level

any ideas?

edit. i think this may have started happening after i installed Xcode 4, but not sure

Comment: Do you have a small example that shows this behavior ? (And note that there's no standard C min/max function or macro, though C++ provides a std::min/std::max template in the `<algorithm>` header)

Answer (score 3):

(it may help to specify the language you're using...)

what you see could be a few things. if you are expecting this to be c++'s `std::min`, then you probably have a rogue `using namespace std;` declared in the global namespace, which is not included ahead of every file.

if this is the case:

1) delete every global `using namespace std` declaration (optional, but worthwhile).

2) and/or qualify `min` with `std::min`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it's a lot of third party code that i don't really want to mod. declaring a min() and max() macro in each problem file was what i did as a temporary fix. It is in both objective-c++ mm files and normal c++ files

Comment: if that's the approach you must take, then it's preferable to declare `using std::min;` in the global namespace for TUs that need it in order to build.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are accessing the math.h libraries or something is wrong with your install. I'd be inclined to suggest removing xcode completely including all developer tools. The read me's have instructions for doing this. Then reboot your machine and reinstall again.

Comment: thanks, i think it might be something to do with recently installing xcode 4 alongside 3... maybe i'll just upgrade to 4